# Drools indecate variable as unexpected

Tags: drools

I wan't return from query Company object. But IDE indecate company as unexpected

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpWrq.png)

What is my error:

```
dialect  "java"

query getBalance(World world, Company company)
    $company := Company(companyName == "Intel") from world.getCompanies()
end

rule "BMWCarsToPerson"
when
    $world : World()

    $company : Company()

    getBalance($world, $company)
    /*$company : Company() from $world.getCompanies()*/

    $manager : Manager() from $company.getManagers()
        exists Car(name == BrandOfCar.BMW) from $manager.getCars()

    $bmwCarsFromManager : Car(
        name == BrandOfCar.BMW
        ) from $manager.getCars()

    $person : Person(
        name == "Elvis"
        ) from $world.getPersons()

    /*$listMageners : List() from $manager*/

then
end
```

Comment: You don't need the `exists Car(name == BrandOfCar.BMW) from $manager.getCars()` as it is followed by a pattern which won't fire unless the exists is true. Therefore it is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't (and cannot) use a query for this simple task. Replace

```
$company : Company()
getBalance($world, $company)
```

by

```
$company: Company( companyName == "Intel" ) from $world.getCompanies()
```

Comment: Thank you. But, I know it, but i wan't test query in Drools.

Comment: Then you should follow the example in the Drools documentation where a query is executed via the API.